# DevExpress Barbuttonitem together with caliburn micro

Tags: wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I would like to know. How can I use dxb:Barbuttonitem together with caliburn micro.
I tried to write this code. But unfortunately it did not work.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
    xmlns:dxr="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/ribbon"
    Title="ShellView"
    Width="300"
    Height="300">
<Grid>
    <dxb:BarManager Name="barManager1">
        <dxb:BarManager.Items>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem Name="Connect" Content="barButtonItem1" />
        </dxb:BarManager.Items>
        <DockPanel >
            <dxr:RibbonControl  DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory Name="ribbonDefaultPageCategory1" Caption="defaultCategory">
                    <dxr:RibbonPage Caption="Home">
                        <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Name="ribbonPageGroup1" Caption="Tools">
                            <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="Connect" />
                        </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                    </dxr:RibbonPage>
                </dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory>
            </dxr:RibbonControl>
            <dxr:RibbonStatusBarControl  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
        </DockPanel>
    </dxb:BarManager>
</Grid>
```

```
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IShell
{
    public void Connect()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello {0}!", "aaa"));
    }

    public bool CanConnect()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I use a standard button, all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by CM since BarButtonItem inherits from FrameworkContentElement (CM supports messages on FrameworkElement only).

The CM forum post can be found [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/218975)

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround for this problem that let's you trigger actions from DX's Bar items. You can use a static bar item and put any of standard controls (or buttons) inside then trigger actions from those elements. Example:

```
  <dxb:BarStaticItem x:Name="LoadAllBarItem">
    <dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Button Content="Load all"
                cal:Message.Attach="LoadAction"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
  </dxb:BarStaticItem>
```